# Issue when Rounding Decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, floating-point

I am building a test billing application, built in rub on rails, Jquery and Postgres DB (using decimal columns)

This is the below way I am storing values, but I think that is not the way it should save the values

Product 1: **57.5**

Charge: **1.7249999999999999**

S-Tax: **0.13799999999999998**

C-Tax: **4.6**

Total: **63.97**

Here, I am not rounding any values other than Total when submitting the form; without rounding the Total will be **63.963**.
So, doing this rounding only for Total and not for others creates issues. For some countries I need to use the precision 2, and others 3

Moreover, I would like to know if this is the correct way to store these values in DB.

Is there any rule like doing the rounding for each column (Charge, S-Tax, C-Tax, and Total)? or any rules for the precision & scale? OR should we convert this to integer?

If we go for integer, should we round it and convert to integer?

What would be the correct data we should store when we submit it? It would be great if someone could suggest, as this has been haunting for some time.

Comment: You say _"using decimal columns"_ but also tagged your question with `floating-point` – can you explain? Are you using decimal values in your database and floats in Ruby? If so, consider using `BigDecimal` or the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem, see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/477037)

Comment: Hi @Stefan, yeah the db column type is Decimal, yes somewhere we are using to_f, but here my confusion is how should be this values (1.7249999999999999) stored in the postgres database? It should be like 1.7249999999999999.round(2) => 1.73 or 1.7249999999999999.round(3) => 1.725.
Why I am using round(3) here, because I need to show 3 decimal for some countries, so will this be fine?

Comment: @Stefan, or we should go this way (0.13799999999999998 * 100).round.to_i, but here also we need to give the number of digits to be rounded off in the round function

Comment: Why do you have 1.724999999999999 in the first place? The value already looks like the result of a rounding error.

Comment: Yeah @stefan, I was doing some calculation and saving it in the db without rounding, and trying to round it and show it in the front-end, I think that is an issue

Answer (score 0):

if you are using rails then you can put the precision scale in the column itself.

"Charge, S-Tax, C-Tax, and Total", you can change the migrations!

e.g.

```
t.decimal "s_tax", precision: 2, scale: 3, null: false
```